# Reordering styles in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, ribbon

I copied one document into another document and it seems that Heading 1 is now moved to a different location int he toolbar (ribbon). Now heading 2 till 6 are visible and on the next line (which I need to scroll manually to), is heading 7 to 9 and 1.

How can I get heading 1 before heading 2 again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by reordering the quick styles gallery.

1. In the toolbar, open the **styles pane** by clicking the little
   arrow button down the bottom right of the **Quick Styles Gallery**.
2. Click the Manage Styles button down the bottom left of the styles
   pane.
3. Click the **Recommended Tab**.
4. Select **Heading 1** from that list Press the **Up** button until
   the priority level becomes before Heading 2 as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, actually on 2010 it was on a slightly different place but with this help I have found it and it works. Thanks!